# Configurable Tooltip on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have Below HTML

```
<html>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtFirst"/></td><td><input type="text" id="txtSecond"/> 
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="divTooltip"></div>
</html>
```

Jquery:

//Validation On Textboxes for removing the HTML Tags

```
    $(document).on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
        var isTags = isHTML($(this).val())

        //Function for checking the html tags
        function isHTML(str) {
            var a = document.createElement('div');
            a.innerHTML = str;
            for (var c = a.childNodes, i = c.length; i--;) {
                if (c[i].nodeType == 1) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (isTags == true) {
            //Clearing the tags
            $(this).val('');
            $('#divTooltip').html('Tags are not allowed')
        }
    })
```

I will be having Comboboxes also in the same page and if the validation fails on those comboboxes I will be again changing the Html of the divTooltip .

What I want is that if the validation fails at any control then the divTooltip should be used as a tooltip for the control under scrutiny . This tooltip should be a bootstrap dynamic.

Kindly guide to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

To set the tooltip of a control simply use `title` property, for example:

```
this.title = 'Tags are not allowed';
```

This will work for all input elements including select.